# Windows 8 update starts and fails with error 80096002

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

Windows 8 install.

Trying to run Windows Update and it immediately fails with error code 80096002

[image]

From the event viewer:

```
Fault bucket -1144026401, type 5
Event Name: WindowsUpdateFailure2
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: 7.8.9200.16384
P2: 80096002
P3: D67661EB-2423-451D-BF5D-13199E37DF28
P4: Scan
P5: 101
P6: Managed
P7: 0
P8: 
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\NonCritical_7.8.9200.16384_76af88d5c6e62bdb7eba9039c59f33bdd44ea3_08a8f74a

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report ID: 56bdc917-6acc-11e2-be6a-005056afe656
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: 785fd21b6f66833f7c0845c8844db318
```

Not sure if it matters, but the computer is joined to a domain, and the logged in user is a domain admin.

Comment: This really sounds like a domain configuration problem. What is your group policy that manages this behavior set to? I was able to find this thread which I would almost guarantee is your problem.  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprogeneral/thread/30423fe0-81fe-488f-ab0e-955854bcf451

Comment: I have WSUS installed. It seems that checking against my WSUS produces the error, while checking against the Windows Update server works fine.

Comment: So that would indicate that your problem is either your missing a required update that allows Windows to accept updates from your WSUS server or your WSUS server is simply not configured correctly.  As I said the thread seems to have the solution you seek I would try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a missing KB on the WSUS server.

KB 2734608 - strangely, that wasn't installed automatically, even that the WSUS updates are set to be automatic.

Going through the [installation of KB 2734608, on this page](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sus/archive/2012/09/05/additional-note-on-kb-2734608-regarding-wsu-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) has sorted it.